# How can i transform this code in ternary operator

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, conditional-operator

i have this code where i am using recursion to console some numbers, without using for loop.

```
let counter = 0;
function test() {
    if(counter <= 50) {
        c.log(counter);
        ++counter;
        test();
    } else {
       return;
    }
}

test(80);
```

is there any way to solve this in one line with ternary operator without using external function like this:

```
let counter = 0;

function doSomething() {
    c.log(counter);
    ++counter;
    test();
}

function test() {
    counter <= 50 ? doSomething() : null;
}

test(80);
```

Comment: do you do something with `n`?

Comment: Why would you want to? Your code is readable as it is, why would you mangle it?

Comment: btw, `else return;` is superfluous if no code is coming later.

Comment: I am curious if there is possible answer on this with ternary operator.

Comment: please add a description what you like to achive. you have in the first a single function with a global counter and you call this function **once** and later `proba`. there is no recursion, just something else which is not clear. the second code has no recursion either.

Comment: I edited the question. the function name was jsut wrong, now there is recursion

Comment: what is with `n`? and what happens in the first block?

Comment: The function prints the number from 0 to 50, with recursion, n is removed it was not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Although I wouldn't recommend it, this would work iff function `proba()` accepts an additional argument. `console.log(var)` returns the value of `var`, in case your `c` is just a shorthand for `console`.

But really, I don't see any recursion in your code. The undefined `proba()` and `test()` function seem independent of each other.

```
let counter = 0;

function test(n) {
    counter <= 50 ? proba(c.log(counter++)) : null;
}

test(80);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an approach without using a global variable.

```js
function test(n) {
    if (n < 0) return; // exit condition
    test(n - 1);       // recursive call
    console.log(n);    // deferred output
}

test(50);
```

Comment: With this shorthand, test(n - 1) and console.log are else blocks? how console.log(n) is waiting and at the end it prints the result ? Can you explain please

Comment: it takes just the given order. maybe an example just three calls is easier to understand. first, with `test(3)`, it takes the check. it is `false`, the next call of `test(2)` follows (no console), then another check is `false` and it goes on with `test(1)` etc until `test(-1)` then  the recursion ends. it follows `console.log(2)` this function ends. it follows `console.log(1)` this function ends. etc until `console.log(3)`.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.I get all, but i dont undertant how whole time n is saved and after that console.log fires five times in a row

Answer (score 0):

```
function test() {
    counter <= 50 ? (c.log(counter), ++counter, test()) : null;
}

test(80);
```